# Shell Script for Bulk renaming of files

Tags: bash, shell, file-rename, batch-rename

I want to recursively rename all files in directory path by changing their prefix.

For Example

```
XYZMyFile.h
XYZMyFile.m
XYZMyFile1.h
XYZMyFile1.m
XYZMyFile2.h
XYZMyFile2.m
```

TO

```
ABCMyFile.h
ABCMyFile.m
ABCMyFile1.h
ABCMyFile1.m
ABCMyFile2.h
ABCMyFile2.m
```

These files are under a directory structure with many layers.  Can someone help me with a shell script for this bulk task?

Comment: Rename first 3 characters from `XYZ` to `ABC`, seems so trivial? What did you try? Did you look up similar answers before posting here?

Comment: use `rename` Perl function on command line. If you familiar with `C++` use my [renrem](https://github.com/k-five/renrem) program or use [drr](https://github.com/k-five/drr) which is on `D` language.

Comment: edit suggestion queue is full :-) and it's easy enough that 4 various ways have been provided

Answer (score 1):

A different approach maybe:

```
ls *.{h,m} | while read a; do n=ABC$(echo $a | sed -e 's/^XYZ//'); mv $a $n; done
```

**Description:**

```
ls *.{h,m} --> Find all files with .h or .m extension
n=ABC --> Add a ABC prefix to the file name
sed -e 's/^XYZ//' --> Removes the XYZ prefix from the file name
mv $a $n --> Performs the rename
```

Comment: ls: *.h: No such file or directory
ls: *.m: No such file or directory. i got these two line as output

Comment: did you `cd` to where the files are located? Where are the files located?

Comment: You may want to add quotes for dealing with any filenames that have spaces in them.  mv "$a" "$n";

Answer (score -1):

Set `globstar` first and then use rename like below:

```
# shopt -s globstar # This will cause '**' to expand to each and everything
# ls -R
.:
nXYZ1.c  nXYZ2.c  nXYZ3.c  subdir  XYZ1.m  XYZ2.m  XYZ3.m
nXYZ1.h  nXYZ2.h  nXYZ3.h  XYZ1.c  XYZ2.c  XYZ3.c
nXYZ1.m  nXYZ2.m  nXYZ3.m  XYZ1.h  XYZ2.h  XYZ3.h

./subdir:
nXYZ1.c  nXYZ1.m  nXYZ2.h  nXYZ3.c  nXYZ3.m  XYZ1.h  XYZ2.c  XYZ2.m  XYZ3.h
nXYZ1.h  nXYZ2.c  nXYZ2.m  nXYZ3.h  XYZ1.c   XYZ1.m  XYZ2.h  XYZ3.c  XYZ3.m
# rename 's/^XYZ(.*.[mh])$/ABC$1/;s/^([^\/]*\/)XYZ(.*.[mh])$/$1ABC$2/' **
# ls -R
.:
ABC1.h  ABC2.m  nXYZ1.c  nXYZ2.c  nXYZ3.c  subdir  XYZ3.c
ABC1.m  ABC3.h  nXYZ1.h  nXYZ2.h  nXYZ3.h  XYZ1.c
ABC2.h  ABC3.m  nXYZ1.m  nXYZ2.m  nXYZ3.m  XYZ2.c

./subdir:
ABC1.h  ABC2.h  ABC3.h  nXYZ1.c  nXYZ1.m  nXYZ2.h  nXYZ3.c  nXYZ3.m  XYZ2.c
ABC1.m  ABC2.m  ABC3.m  nXYZ1.h  nXYZ2.c  nXYZ2.m  nXYZ3.h  XYZ1.c   XYZ3.c
# shopt -u globstar # Unset gobstar
```

This may be the simplest way to achieve your objective.

---

<sub>**Note1 :** Here I am not changing `nXYZ` to `nABC` as you have noticed. If they are meant to be changed the simplified `rename` command would be</sub>

```
rename 's/XYZ(.*.[mh])$/ABC$1/' **
```

<sub>**Note2 :** The question has mentioned nothing about multiple occurrences of `XYZ`. So nothing done in this regard.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

For non-recursive, you can use **rename** which is a **perl** script:

```
rename -v -n 's/^.+(?=MyFile)/what-you-want/' *.{h,m}
```

*test*:

```
 dir >  ls | cat -n
     1  XYZMyFile1.h
     2  XYZMyFile1.m
     3  XYZMyFile.h
     4  XYZMyFile.m
 dir >  
 dir >  rename -v -n 's/^.+(?=MyFile)/what-you-want/' *.{h,m}
rename(XYZMyFile1.h, what-you-wantMyFile1.h)
rename(XYZMyFile1.m, what-you-wantMyFile1.m)
rename(XYZMyFile.h, what-you-wantMyFile.h)
rename(XYZMyFile.m, what-you-wantMyFile.m)
 dir >
```

and for recursive,use `find` + this command

---

If you do not have access to **rename**, you can use **perl** directly like so:

```
perl -le '($old=$_) && s/^xzy/abc/g && rename($old,$_) for <*.[mh]>'
```

and here is a screen-shot

[image]

---

and with [renrem](https://github.com/k-five/renrem), a CLI I developed using C++, specifically for renaming

[image: renrem]

Comment: after XYZ MYFILE is not same. it can be any filename. XYZMyFile1.h XYZnewFile.h, XYZOldFile.h. Only thing common is prefix. And I want to replace that. Your script seems to take MYFile into consideration, so can you modify your script.

Comment: Yes, if you be more specific please. I developed three apps just on renaming files. It is so easy for me if you explain your pattern exactly.

Answer (score -1):

Easy `find` and `rename` (the binary in /usr/bin, not the Perl function mentioned)

Yes, there is a command to do this non-recursive already.

`rename XYZ ABC XYZ*`

```
rename --help

Usage:
 rename [options] expression replacement file...

Options:
 -v, --verbose    explain what is being done
 -s, --symlink    act on symlink target

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see rename(1).
```

edit: missed the "many layers of directory" part of the question, b/c it's a little messy.  Adding the find.

Easiest to remember:

```
find . -type f -name "*.pdf" -exec rename XYZ ABC {} \;
```

Probably faster to finish:

```
find . -type d -not -path "*/\.*" -not -name ".*" -exec rename XYZ ABC {}/*.pdf \;
```

I'm not sure how to get easier than one command line of code.